# Is it possible to have 2 different SKU's of Visual Studio 2010 installed at the same time?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm working as a consultant and I have Visual Studio 2010 Professionel installed, but I'm about to do some work that requires me to have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate installed, which my client will provide me with.
But I need to use the Professionel version for other projects while having the Ultimate version installed. (I can't use the Ultimate version for my other projects due to legal issues) Is it possible to have 2 different SKU's installed side by side without them interfering with eachother?
If not, I guess I could install VS Ultimate on a VM, but I would prefer if it was possible to have them installed side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different SKUs of the same version of Visual Studio (ie. 2008, 2010 etc...) cannot be installed side by side.

Your best way forward is to use a VM.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I believe you, but do you have a reference or is it from personal experience you know this?

Comment: @Gunder - Personal experience mostly. If you try to install Ultimate over Professional you end up with an upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use virtualization?  Create a virtual image on your machine with your preferred OS, and then install VS on that VM?

So simple, and at the end of the project, dump or archive the VM.

Comment: The OP mentions that he can do this but prefers not to if possible.